# Linear graph connect from point to point not site to site

Tags: r

I'm trying to connect lines from the first point to the next and so on to make it look nice. Whereas my data plots are going from site to site instead and are producing a messy graph.

[image]

This is what code I have been running for plotting linear:

```
plot(Pcoa_veg_axis1~mds_axis2,data=corr,type="l")
text(Pcoa_veg_axis1~mds_axis2,labels=rownames(corr),data=corr,cex=0.6,pos=3)
```

Here is part of my dataset.

```
    Pcoa_veg_axis1 Pcoa_veg_axis2   mds_axis1   mds_axis2
C9A    -0.299110532   -0.058382319 -21.6181771 -19.0808780
C9B    -0.009916011    0.063823361 -21.2886076 -16.2458319
C1B    -0.071099349    0.089240037 -20.2455757 -13.0021687
C1A    -0.092417933    0.032765145 -18.4715225 -11.5300869
C11B   -0.218068341   -0.053807421 -19.3427890  -8.9486301
C2A     0.087473116   -0.115803489  30.3401723  -7.3020944
C11A   -0.093391255   -0.027711404 -18.9097868  -5.6414492
C2B    -0.042320306    0.090588191  23.4684750  -5.4059155
C3A     0.183038811    0.090588191 -16.7730780  -5.4059155
FB/B   -0.165827685   -0.036144104 -10.6988548  -5.0396790
C12A    0.134159302   -0.081690763  36.4707741  -3.6945480
FB/A   -0.116359969    0.139636485  38.6254936  -2.9253639
C6B     0.131707200   -0.057281092  50.8792881  -2.5926473
C13B   -0.022782638    0.068269838  37.9511861  -0.2661316
TD/A    0.006451748   -0.007112111 -18.1204653   0.3473569
C4B    -0.281738504   -0.003255377 -18.3911929   1.3832630
C6A     0.113244380   -0.040225070  39.1513037   1.3874098
C13A    0.047606141   -0.015426874  32.5673096   3.0725594
C4A    -0.449091292   -0.030750493  17.5590863   3.7708687
C8A    -0.127876087    0.297497450   0.9868649   4.5940826
C10B    0.116260403   -0.179166687   5.3197647   5.8221690
C12B    0.254295772    0.206431510  -8.7477061   6.2717319
C5A     0.145798135   -0.111588933  12.3149887   7.2310145
TD/B    0.072191314   -0.032797811 -15.1216737   7.4497430
C3B     0.247921674    0.080663295 -15.8976194   8.4725934
C10A    0.030515962   -0.407922948  -6.4846175   8.6865969
C7B     0.206852521    0.050633262 -16.4601287   8.8960884
C8B     0.195911626    0.119012564 -14.3804112   9.0421539
C7A     0.074906500   -0.009381470 -16.4100447   9.7453561
C5B    -0.058334700    0.037365311 -13.1542838  12.1222324
```

I even used the order function to try and make the lines connect how I want them. But for now I need `MDS2` on the x axis and `PCOA1` on y axis.

I want the graph to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput(corr)` and post the resulting output here if you want to have someone help you with this. I think there is nothing wrong with your code; it's just that the data is erratic and points & labels overlap. Can you group your data and plot by group? Could you order by x value?  Use `ggrepel` with `ggplot2` to avoid label overlap. Do you really need a line plot? What about plotting just point and labels?

Comment: The image you show above looks like you did not sort the data. But since you say that you ordered it and now the lines look right, I don't think that's the problem, anymore. So, what is the problem, now? Just the axis labels? They could be passed to the plot as arguments `xlab="MDS2", ylab="PCOA1"`. Or is there another problem I don't see?